# 100MBps instead of 1000MBps (ethernet)

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, powerline-networking

[[my network card specifications]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIjAX.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1osIh.png)recently I bought a netgear PL1000 ethernet adapter. It has a maximum download speed of 1000Mbps. However I only get around 50Mbps in a internetspeed test. You can see my networkcard sending and receiving 1000Mbps in the added picture (the picture is in dutch so if you don't understand let me know). Also my router sends 1000Mbps so thats not the problem either. Can there be a maximum downloadspeed of my ethernetcables or powerline? If so please let me know.

Comment: Powerlines are not that fast.

Comment: Note that the wiring of power lines (in the walls of your house) is likely to NOT be adapted to the high speed signals required by 1000Mbps. Expect losses for every (high frequency related) deficiency in the physical wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Powerline rated speeds are almost entirely marketing. First and foremost, unlike Ethernet, these are not duplex connections. In fact, they’re much more similar to Wi-Fi, where you see a similar difference between rated speed and actual speed.

Then there’s also the fact that you’re using wires that are in no way rated for high-speed data transmission. There’s an additional catch, too: Every device that is drawing power actually produces electrical noise that will affect Powerline transmissions. Switching-mode power supplies (like your PC’s) are especially bad. You will also experience problems when connecting across different electrical phases, if that’s a thing where you’re living.

Depending on how the building was constructed (reinforced concrete, wood, whatever) you may get much better speeds with Wi-Fi 5/6.

(The *link speed* you see on your network card is only about the connection to the Powerline adapter, not the Powerline link itself.)

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the speed that is to be expected.

The Netgear PL1000 is a gigabit adapter. It is capable of 1000Mbs. That is bits, not bytes. That would equal 125MBs maximum theoretical speed. With overhead taken into account 100MBs is about right. The same for your gigabit Ethernet controller. Your router would also be gigabit.

Comment: But on the site where I bought it it says internetspeeds up to 1000Mbps and indeed a Gigabit Ethernet adapter. I have seen reviews of people who do get the 1000Mbps speed. Also the maximum speed I have measured is around 60Mbps.

Comment: Is it able that it's because of my netwerk card, its a Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller. Do you mean because of the Gigabit and not Gigabyte?

Comment: @Sibj2064 following our discussions on your other question - Your problem is likely not the Qualcom network card its the Powerline adaptors.  While powerline devices are a legit network tool, their marketing is pure snake-oil (like WIFI, but worse!).  The 1000 megabits is a theoretical maximum you can never get close to reaching in real world scenarios.  This is likely your issue.

Comment: I see now , my connection improved so i'm just going to keep it like this. Thanks for your help.